# Convert BigDecimal to BigInt Scala

Tags: scala

How to convert BigDecimal to BigInt in Scala?

I am trying to run the following code:

```
val x:BigDecimal = 2.335656787776;
    val y = new BigInt(x);
```

The Error I get is:

```
Found:    (PlayGround.x : BigDecimal)
Required: java.math.BigInteger
```

Whereas when I do:

```
val x:BigDecimal = 2.335656787776;
val y = BigInt(x);
```

I get:

```
None of the overloaded alternatives of method apply in object BigInt with types
 (x: java.math.BigInteger): BigInt
 (x: String, radix: Int): BigInt
 (x: String): BigInt
 (numbits: Int, rnd: scala.util.Random): BigInt
 (bitlength: Int, certainty: Int, rnd: scala.util.Random): BigInt
 (signum: Int, magnitude: Array[Byte]): BigInt
 (x: Array[Byte]): BigInt
 (l: Long): BigInt
 (i: Int): BigInt
match arguments ((PlayGround.x : BigDecimal))
```

How can I cast BigDecimal into BigInt?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`toBigInt` does what you need. From [docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/math/BigDecimal.html#toBigInt:scala.math.BigInt)

> Converts this BigDecimal to a scala.BigInt.

Which does the following:

```
new BigInt(this.bigDecimal.toBigInteger)
```

There is also [`toBigIntExact`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/math/BigDecimal.html#toBigIntExact:Option%5Bscala.math.BigInt%5D) which returns an option, if the conversion can be done losslessly.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.toBigInt`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/math/BigDecimal.html#toBigInt:scala.math.BigInt)

```scala
val x: BigDecimal = 2.335656787776
x.toBigInt // returns 2
```

Answer (score 0):

A workAround that I found is:

```
val x:BigDecimal = 2.335656787776;
val y = BigInt("%.0f".format(x));
```

Is there any better way for the same?